# How to handle if/else scope issue for variables set in "if condition" (Destroying GameObject in C#)

Tags: c#, object, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity and making a program that makes spheres appear once an object is clicked and then I want to delete the spheres when it is clicked again.

The problem is that on the initial run through the spheres are not defined since they are only created if the object is has not been clicked (`!isSelected`). I create them as an array of GameObjects but when I enter the else condition I receive the error *NullReferenceException: Object Reference not set to an instance of an object Cube.OnMouseDown( ).* I think this is because I originally set `GameObject[] Spheres = null` in the beginning. How should I initialize this variable so that I don't receive this error?

Also in general what's the best practice for using a variable that is defined in an if statement and modified in an else statement?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {

    bool isSelected = false;

    void OnMouseDown() {
        Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        GameObject[] Spheres = null;

        if (!isSelected) {
            isSelected = true;
            rend.material.color = Color.blue; //#588c7e
            Vector3[] vertices = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices;
            Vector3[] verts = removeDuplicates(vertices);
            Spheres = drawSpheres(verts);
        } else {
            rend.material.color = Color.white;
            print("destroy verts");
            for (int i=0; i<Spheres.Length; i++) {
                Destroy(Spheres[i]);
            }
            isSelected = false;
        }

    }
   GameObject[] drawSpheres(Vector3[] verts) {
        GameObject[] Spheres = new GameObject[verts.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < verts.Length; i++) {
            Spheres[i] = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            Spheres[i].transform.position = verts[i];
            Spheres[i].transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0.8F, 0.8F, 0.8F);
            Spheres[i].AddComponent<VertClicked>();
        }
        return Spheres;
    }

}
```

**NOTE:** I removed the removeDuplicates(), Start() and Update() functions from this class as I didn't think they contributed to the question.

Comment: Correct. Setting the array to `null` is why you're having that issue. Is your -`OnMouseDown` method an event? If so, it should have arguments, one of which will be the object that was clicked. If it is a `Sphere`, then you should delete it; otherwise, create a new one.

Comment: I changed it to a declaration `GameObject[] Spheres;` and placed it outside as a global variable and it worked. Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: The problem with that is that it will delete all the spheres. If you wanted to do just single spheres, then you'll have to redesign. I'd put an on clicked event on the object instead to delete it from within the class instead.

Comment: But Stack Overflow doesn't like "best practice" questions as no one knows your entire system like you do. There could be many decisions you made that we're not privy to. Making us aware of them all would render 99% of the questions unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variables before the if statement just as you did Spheres.